# onclick button toggle icon not working in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, toggle, react-icons

Here i try to toggle react icons when click the button but it still not working:

Here is my code:

```
const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

   <button onClick={handleClick} className="top-rated-car-react-button">
            {anchorEl ? (
              <MdFavoriteBorder
                style={{
                  color: "#F76631", 
                }}
              />
            ) : (
              <MdFavorite
                style={{
                  color: "#F76631",
                }}
              />
            )}
   </button>
```

I try with react icons buttons onClick event but it is not toggling with both icons if `MdFavoriteBorder` it should change with `MdFavorite` when click the button same as when `MdFavorite` active change with `MdFavoriteBorder`

Comment: When do you call handle close?

Comment: when `MdFavoriteBorder` active it should change with `MdFavorite` if click same as both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks too complicated. I would create a boolean state which I would toggle then like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { MdFavorite, MdFavoriteBorder } from "react-icons/md";

export default function App() {
  const [favorite, setFavorite] = useState(false);
  const toggleFavorite = () => setFavorite((prev) => !prev);

  return (
    <button onClick={toggleFavorite} className="top-rated-car-react-button">
      {favorite ? (
        <MdFavoriteBorder style={{ color: "#F76631" }} />
      ) : (
        <MdFavorite style={{ color: "#F76631" }} />
      )}
    </button>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-poincare-wm1ite

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a easy way like

```js
const [changeIcon, setChangeIcon] = useState(true);
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(!changeIcon);
  };

   <button onClick={handleClick} className="top-rated-car-react-button">
            {changeIcon ? (
              <MdFavoriteBorder
                style={{
                  color: "#F76631", 
                }}
              />
            ) : (
              <MdFavorite
                style={{
                  color: "#F76631",
                }}
              />
            )}
   </button>
```

On click the setChangeIcon will set the value of changeIcon to false of true depending on previous state and the component will reload and the icon will be toggled